# In ReactJS, Where to put stuff that gets run one time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, but have been doing Javascript at a so-so level for years.  In most of my Apps, before ReactJS, I would have an init() function where I did things like:

1. change document title
2. do a console.log that says 'Name of app version xxx initialized'
3. add a version number to the bottom of the page
4. etc, etc.

In ReactJS, where would I do such things?

EDIT: I mean, usually I will have something like this:

```
function init() {
  document.title = APP.title;
  console.log(APP.title + ' version ' + APP.version + ' initialized.');
  $( '#bottom-info' ).text( APP.version );
}
init();
```

How would this look, and where would it go, using ReactJS?

Answer (score 2):

`public/index.html` is where you can start with. All html is getting rendered from this file where you can change title, link stylesheets, etc. You'll also find the root element like:

```js
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is where your react application will be attached.

In the `src/index.js` file, you can see the react component is being attached using:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, // react component
  document.getElementById('root') // is attached to html root element
);
```

Where, you can log the name of the app, its version, etc. I hope you can dive into this further following `App` component.

Comment: @SungKim, why are you adding `<!-- language-all: lang-js -->`? Can you explain it?

Comment: It's a language highlight syntax for StackOverflow posts/questions - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/4035  I added it to make the code readable 

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I added some code so you can see what I mean.  I mean adding these things dynamically, not just adding them to index.html.